# What kind of information does the vscode's marketplace.json shows?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just found a code block that shows a list of malicious (I guess) extension list?
Here is the link: https://az764295.vo.msecnd.net/extensions/marketplace.json

```json
{
    "malicious": [
        "visualstuiocode.emmet",
        "joaomoreno.banana",
        "JacobeanResearchandDevelopmentLLC.vscode-scxml-preview",
        "joaquin6.package-watch",
        "KazuoCode.gthubsum",
        "MaxGotovkin.tslens"
    ],
    "deprecated": {
        "msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome": {
            "disallowInstall": true,
            "extension": {
                "id": "ms-vscode.js-debug",
                "displayName": "JavaScript Debugger"
            }
        },
        "adashen.vscode-tomcat": {
            "disallowInstall": true,
            "extension": {
                "id": "redhat.vscode-community-server-connector",
                "displayName": "Community Server Connectors"
            }
        },
        "SummerSun.vscode-jetty": {
            "disallowInstall": true,
            "extension": {
                "id": "redhat.vscode-community-server-connector",
                "displayName": "Community Server Connectors"
            }
        },
        "abusaidm.html-snippets": true,
        "ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-tslint-plugin": true,
        "eg2.tslint": true,
        "zenclabs.reactpreview": {
            "disallowInstall": true,
            "extension": {
                "id": "zenclabs.previewjs",
                "displayName": "Preview.js"
            }
        },
        ...
```

Is there anything I need look into vscode if it contains any of the listed extension or something?